# available languages & their keys in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am developing an application which support multiple languages I know how to parse and pass the key of any languages programmatically.
Now I want to know that how can I know which are the supported languages & their keys in iOS

-Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the link which will help you see how many languages are supported in iOS :

http://kb.applingua.com/2011/07/which-languages-does-ios-support/